# reporting services virtual directory

Tags: reporting-services

i have iis7 i had build the report using business intelligence studio but i cant able to deploy the reports.it has given the error that "you are not attached to the server" but i install the reporting services in my admin account only

Answer (score 0):

Can you log into the management website using your browser: http://localhost/reports ???